# How to save regex backreferences to an array during preg_replace or preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Here's the problem: I have a database full of articles marked up in XHTML. Our application uses [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/) to generate PDFs. An artifact of that is that footnotes are marked up inline, using the following pattern:

```
<p>Some paragraph text<span class="fnt">This is the text of a footnote</span>.</p>
```

Prince replaces every `span.fnt` with a numeric footnote marker, and renders the enclosed text as a footnote at the bottom of the page.

We want to render the same content in ebook formats, and XHTML is a great starting point, but the inline footnotes are terrible. What I want to do is convert the footnotes to endnotes in my ebook build script.

This is what I'm thinking:

1. Create an empty array called `$endnotes` to store the endnote text.
2. Set a variable `$endnote_no` to zero. This variable will hold the current endnote number, to display inline as an endnote marker, and to be used in linking the endnote marker to the particular endnote.
3. Use `preg_replace` or `preg_replace_callback` to find every instance of `<span class="fnt">(.*?)</span>`.
4. Increment `$endnote_no` for each instance, and replace the inline `span` with `'<sup><a href="#endnote_`' . $endnote_no . '">' .$endnote_no . ''`
5. Push the footnote text to the `$endnotes` array so that I can use it at the end of the document.
6. After replacing all the footnotes with numeric endnote references, iterate through the `$endnotes` array to spit out the endnotes as an ordered list in XHTML.

This process is a bit beyond my PHP comprehension, and I get lost when I try to translate this into code. Here's what I have so far, which I mainly cobbled together based on code examples I found in the PHP documentation:

```
$endnotes = array();
$endnote_no = 0;
class Endnoter {

  public function replace($subject) {
    $this->endnote_no = 0;
    return preg_replace_callback('`<span class="fnt">(.*?)</span>`', array($this, '_callback'), $subject);
  }

  public function _callback($matches) {
    array_push($endnotes, $1);
    return '<sup><a href="#endnote_' . $this->endnote_no++ . '">' . $this->endnote_no . '</a></sup>';
  }
}
```

...

```
$replacer = new Endnoter();
$replacer->replace($body);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($endnotes); // Just checking to see if the $endnotes are there.
echo '</pre>';
```

Any guidance would be helpful, especially if there is a simpler way to get there.

Comment: If this was another language I'd say yes, there is a nicer way of doing this. In PHP I believe the answer is no, but I might be mistaken. My idea is that instead of calling a function that does the whole thing, and giving it another function as a parameter, you use a loop and only do one replacement in each loop iteration. In Perl, for instance, you could do this: `my $endnote_no = 0; my @endnotes; while ($subject =~ s!<span class="fnt">(.*?)</span>!<sup><a href="#endnote_$endnote_no">$endnote_no</a></sup>!) { $endnote_no++; push @endnotes, $1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about a simpler way, but you were halfway there. This seems to work.

I just cleaned it up a bit, moved the variables inside your class and added an output method to get the footnote list.

```
class Endnoter
{
    private $number_of_notes = 0;
    private $footnote_texts = array();

    public function replace($input) {

        return preg_replace_callback('#<span class="fnt">(.*)</span>#i', array($this, 'replace_callback'), $input);

    }

    protected function replace_callback($matches) {

        // the text sits in the matches array
        // see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php
        $this->footnote_texts[] = $matches[1];

        return '<sup><a href="#endnote_'.(++$this->number_of_notes).'">'.$this->number_of_notes.'</a></sup>';

    }

    public function getEndnotes() {
        $out = array();
        $out[] = '<ol>';

        foreach($this->footnote_texts as $text) {
            $out[] = '<li>'.$text.'</li>';
        }

        $out[] = '</ol>';

        return implode("\n", $out);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Florian! This is almost perfect. The only thing I can't figure out is how to add an id to each list item in the getEndnotes() function, so that the ids match the links established by the replace_callback(), like so: <li id="endnote_N">, where "N" is the index + 1.

Comment: Cancel that: I got it! `$i = 0;
    foreach($this->footnote_texts as $text) {
      $i++;
      $out[] = '<li id="endnote_'.$i.'">'.$text.'</li>';
    }`

Answer (score 2):

First, you're best off *not* using a regex for HTML manipulation; see here:
[How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

However, if you really want to go that route, there are a few things wrong with your code:

1. ```
   return '<sup><a href="#endnote_' . $this->endnote_no++ . '">' . $this->endnote_no . '</a></sup>';
   ```

   if endnote_no is 1, for example this will produce

   ```
   '<sup><a href="#endnote_1">2</a></sup>';
   ```

   If those values are both supposed to be the same, you want to increment endnote_no first:

   ```
   return '<sup><a href="#endnote_' . ++$this->endnote_no . '">' . $this->endnote_no . '</a></sup>';
   ```

   Note the ++ in front of the call instead of after.
2. ```
   array_push($endnotes, $1);
   ```

   `$1` is not a defined value. You're looking for the array you passed in to the callback, so you want `$matches[1]`
3. ```
   print_r($endnotes);
   ```

   `$endnotes` is not defined outside the class, so you either want a getter function to retrieve `$endnotes` (*usually* preferable) or make the variable public in the class. With a getter:

   ```
   class Endnotes {
       private $endnotes = array();
       //replace any references to $endnotes in your class with $this->endnotes and add a function:

       public function getEndnotes() {
           return $this->endnotes;
       }
   }
   //and then outside
   print_r($replacer->getEndnotes());
   ```
4. `preg_replace_callback` doesn't pass by reference, so you aren't actually modifying the original string. `$replacer->replace($body);` should be `$body = $replacer->replace($body);` unless you want to pass body by reference into the `replace()` function and update its value there.

Comment: Thank you @ChicagoRedSox! I think I followed your reasoning and implemented what you suggested, but now I see this error: "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"; it repeats for every match in the source.

Thanks for the tip about XML parsing--I'll look into that as I am able!

Comment: Did you declare `$endnotes` as an array (`private $endnotes = array()` or `private $endnotes = []` if you're using PHP >= 5.4)? Also did you replace the call to `$endnotes` with `$this->endnotes`? `array_push($this->endnotes, $matches[1]);` Any references to the `$endnotes` variable inside the class should be replaced with `$this->endnotes`.